# JOIN ERROR in big query SELECT statement: USING OR Operator with LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have the below select statement.  I am using a LEFT JOIN to push two tables together.  There are two conditions where the LEFT JOIN should work:

Condition 1: ATTOM_ID.  ATTOM ID is the unique Identifier
Condition 2: ZIP, LAST NAME, and FULL ADDRESS.  These fields are string fields and all three must match to be a JOIN.

Any other condition should result in a NULL, hence the LEFT JOIN.  If either condition passes, the JOIN should occur, which is why I wanted an OR statement here.

for some reason Google Big Query does not like the query because I have an OR in it.  The error I get is:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.
```

Here is the SQL Statement.  All other issues on this statement work.  Is there a GBQ limitation on using LEFT JOINS and the "OR" operator?  Thanks.

```
  SELECT 
  Source, 
  FirstName, 
  LastName,
  MiddleName, 
  Gender, 
  Age, 
  DOB, 
  Address, 
  Address2,
  City, 
  State, 
  Zip, 
  Zip4, 
  TimeZone, 
  Income, 
  HomeValue, 
  Networth, 
  MaritalStatus, 
  IsRenter, 
  HasChildren, 
  CreditRating, 
  Investor, 
  LinesOfCredit, 
  InvestorRealEstate, 
  Traveler, 
  Pets, 
  MailResponder, 
  Charitable, 
  PolicalDonations, 
  PoliticalParty, 
  coalesce(P.ATTOM_ID, T.ATTOM_ID) as ATTOM_ID,
  coalesce(P.GEOID, T.GEOID) as GEOID,
  Score,
  Score1,
  Score2,
  Score3,
  Score4,
  Score5,
  PropertyLatitude AS Latitude,
  PropertyLongitude AS Longitude
  FROM `db.ds.table1` P
 LEFT JOIN `db.ds.table2` T
ON 1 = 
CASE 
    WHEN (P.ATTOM_ID = T.ATTOM_ID) 
        THEN 1
    WHEN P.Zip = T. PropertyAddressZIP
            AND ( 
                    LOWER(P.LastName) = LOWER(T.DeedOwner1NameLast)
                    OR LOWER(P.LastName) = LOWER(T.PartyOwner1NameLast)
                )
            AND ( 
                    STRPOS(LOWER(P.Address), LOWER(T.PropertyAddressFull) ) > 0
                    OR STRPOS(LOWER(T.PropertyAddressFull), LOWER(P.Address) ) > 0 
                )
            AND IFNULL(T.PropertyAddressFull,'') != ''
        THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Your conditions don't seem to satisfy the condition that the error message is talking about.

Comment: That's what I thought at first too, but when I just did " ATTOM_ID OR ZIP" clauses, and removed the other three, the error remained.

Comment: Does it help to put parens around everything below the first OR?

Comment: unfortunately no.  updated query.

Comment: `coalesce(P.ATTOM_ID, T.ATTOM_ID) as ATTOM_ID` :: the order of the arguments seems unlogical.

Comment: I know, it's weird.  but that's where they wanted it.

Comment: It's a referenced column, not a ID column in this table.  A FK from the Table1 perspective.  PK for Table2.  in this case, the owner wants it to remain in the FK position in column order.

Comment: that order is to support scenario when match is based on condition 2 and ATTOM_ID in Table1 is NULL - so make sense to me  - check my answer for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a different approach? Can you split the `OR` in your `JOIN` condition, create two `INNER JOIN` queries and `UNION` them together?

```
SELECT 
    Source, 
    FirstName, 
    LastName,
    MiddleName, 
    Gender, 
    Age, 
    DOB, 
    Address, 
    Address2,
    City, 
    State, 
    Zip, 
    Zip4, 
    TimeZone, 
    Income, 
    HomeValue, 
    Networth, 
    MaritalStatus, 
    IsRenter, 
    HasChildren, 
    CreditRating, 
    Investor, 
    LinesOfCredit, 
    InvestorRealEstate, 
    Traveler, 
    Pets, 
    MailResponder, 
    Charitable, 
    PolicalDonations, 
    PoliticalParty, 
    coalesce(P.ATTOM_ID, T.ATTOM_ID) as ATTOM_ID,
    coalesce(P.GEOID, T.GEOID) as GEOID,
    Score,
    Score1,
    Score2,
    Score3,
    Score4,
    Score5,
    PropertyLatitude AS Latitude,
    PropertyLongitude AS Longitude
FROM `db.ds.Table1` P
INNER JOIN `db.ds.Table2` T ON (P.ATTOM_ID = T.ATTOM_ID) 

UNION

SELECT 
    Source, 
    FirstName, 
    LastName,
    MiddleName, 
    Gender, 
    Age, 
    DOB, 
    Address, 
    Address2,
    City, 
    State, 
    Zip, 
    Zip4, 
    TimeZone, 
    Income, 
    HomeValue, 
    Networth, 
    MaritalStatus, 
    IsRenter, 
    HasChildren, 
    CreditRating, 
    Investor, 
    LinesOfCredit, 
    InvestorRealEstate, 
    Traveler, 
    Pets, 
    MailResponder, 
    Charitable, 
    PolicalDonations, 
    PoliticalParty, 
    coalesce(P.ATTOM_ID, T.ATTOM_ID) as ATTOM_ID,
    coalesce(P.GEOID, T.GEOID) as GEOID,
    Score,
    Score1,
    Score2,
    Score3,
    Score4,
    Score5,
    PropertyLatitude AS Latitude,
    PropertyLongitude AS Longitude
FROM `db.ds.Table1` P
INNER JOIN `db.ds.Table2` T ON P.Zip = T. PropertyAddressZIP
            AND ( 
                    LOWER(P.LastName) = LOWER(T.DeedOwner1NameLast)
                    OR LOWER(P.LastName) = LOWER(T.PartyOwner1NameLast)
                )
            AND ( 
                    STRPOS(LOWER(P.Address), LOWER(T.PropertyAddressFull) ) > 0
                    OR STRPOS(LOWER(T.PropertyAddressFull), LOWER(P.Address) ) > 0 
                )
            AND IFNULL(T.PropertyAddressFull,'') != ''
```

Comment: As frustrating as not being able to use an OR statement with a LEFT JOIN in GBQ, this query works.  Thanks!

Comment: @arcee123 - this still leaves out those entries from Table1 where no any match in T2 - right?

Answer (score 1):

Below is simplified example of your issue

```
#standardSQL
WITH `db.ds.Table1` AS (
  SELECT NULL id, '12345' zip, 'abc' name UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '23456', 'vwu' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 id, '12347' zip, 'abd' name 
), `db.ds.Table2` AS (
  SELECT 2 id, '12346' zip, 'xyz' name UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '12345' zip, 'abc' name 
)
SELECT p, t FROM `db.ds.Table1` p
LEFT JOIN `db.ds.Table2` t
ON p.id = t.id OR p.zip = t.zip
```

it produces `Error: LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.`

You can rewrite above as

```
#standardSQL
WITH `db.ds.Table1` AS (
  SELECT NULL id, '12345' zip, 'abc' name UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '23456', 'vwu' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 id, '12347' zip, 'abd' name 
), `db.ds.Table2` AS (
  SELECT 2 id, '12346' zip, 'xyz' name UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '12345' zip, 'abc' name 
)
SELECT 
  COALESCE(p.id, t.id) AS id,
  p.zip,
  p.name
FROM (
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(p) p , ANY_VALUE(IF(p.id = t.id OR p.zip = t.zip, t, NULL)) t
  FROM `db.ds.Table1` p
  CROSS JOIN `db.ds.Table2` t
  GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(p)
)
```

here you are simply moving all your conditions inside  IF() function and replace LEFT JOIN with CROSS JOIN

result is

```
Row id  zip     name     
1   3   12345   abc  
2   2   23456   vwu  
3   4   12347   abd
```

as you can see - you are not missing id=4 from Table1

Hope, you can adopt this to your specific query (should be straight forward copy-pasting)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the last part of the join condition to a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 
  Source, 
  <lots_of_columns>
  FROM `db.ds.Table1` P
 LEFT JOIN `db.ds.Table2` T
 ON (P.ATTOM_ID = T.ATTOM_ID)
 OR (
   P.Zip = T. PropertyAddressZIP
  AND ( LOWER(P.LastName) = LOWER(T.DeedOwner1NameLast)
    OR LOWER(P.LastName) = LOWER(T.PartyOwner1NameLast))
  AND ( STRPOS(LOWER(P.Address), LOWER(T.PropertyAddressFull) ) > 0
    OR STRPOS(LOWER(T.PropertyAddressFull), LOWER(P.Address) ) > 0 )
  )
  WHERE IFNULL(T.PropertyAddressFull,'') != '';
```

That may be where the issue is coming from, since it doesn't reference both tables in the join.

Comment: I updated the query in the question to conform with your suggestion. so you can see the latest.  Thanks!

Comment: Logically, this would be incorrect, as putting `IFNULL(T.PropertyAddressFull,'') != ''` in the `WHERE` will make that filter apply to the first part of the `OR` in the  JOIN condition (`(P.ATTOM_ID = T.ATTOM_ID)`)

Comment: Yeah, you are right.  It won't fall under the `OR ()` block.  Scratch that :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a `CASE` as the join clause?

```
SELECT 
    Source, 
    FirstName, 
    LastName,
    MiddleName, 
    Gender, 
    Age, 
    DOB, 
    Address, 
    Address2,
    City, 
    State, 
    Zip, 
    Zip4, 
    TimeZone, 
    Income, 
    HomeValue, 
    Networth, 
    MaritalStatus, 
    IsRenter, 
    HasChildren, 
    CreditRating, 
    Investor, 
    LinesOfCredit, 
    InvestorRealEstate, 
    Traveler, 
    Pets, 
    MailResponder, 
    Charitable, 
    PolicalDonations, 
    PoliticalParty, 
    coalesce(P.ATTOM_ID, T.ATTOM_ID) as ATTOM_ID,
    coalesce(P.GEOID, T.GEOID) as GEOID,
    Score,
    Score1,
    Score2,
    Score3,
    Score4,
    Score5,
    PropertyLatitude AS Latitude,
    PropertyLongitude AS Longitude
FROM `db.ds.Table1` P
LEFT JOIN `db.ds.Table2` T ON 1 = 
CASE 
    WHEN (P.ATTOM_ID = T.ATTOM_ID) 
        THEN 1
    WHEN P.Zip = T. PropertyAddressZIP
            AND ( 
                    LOWER(P.LastName) = LOWER(T.DeedOwner1NameLast)
                    OR LOWER(P.LastName) = LOWER(T.PartyOwner1NameLast)
                )
            AND ( 
                    STRPOS(LOWER(P.Address), LOWER(T.PropertyAddressFull) ) > 0
                    OR STRPOS(LOWER(T.PropertyAddressFull), LOWER(P.Address) ) > 0 
                )
            AND IFNULL(T.PropertyAddressFull,'') != ''
        THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Thank you so much aaron.  No change.  errori still exists.  Query updated to your specification in question.